# -2.5V Power Issue

Tags: power-supply, power, operational-amplifier, short-circuit

I'm having some issues diagnosing one of my PCBs. My goal is to provide an opamp with +-2.5V. I'm getting 5V (3A) from a DC barrel jack in the circuit. I'm using the MAX735 to create -5V and feeding it into a LM237 to get it to -2.5V. I'm using an LM350T to step down 5V to 2.5V which works fine. The problem I'm having is when I connect this circuit into the other circuit with the op amps, the -2.5V drops to -1.38V. When I disconnect the 2.5V source to the op amp (lmp7721) circuit, it rises to -2.25V. The +2.5V rail remains constant despite connecting it to the load. I suspect the problem is the MAX735 and the current draw- which causes a voltage sag. If that's the issue (which I'm unsure) I'm thinking of wiring up another in parallel to allow for more current draw, however; I'd love to hear any suggestions or inputs that you may have!

[image: I chose 3 100uF capacitors because it smoothed out the noise much more than a 100uF cap. The datasheet suggests 100uF though.]

***************(Solved by switching to MAX1044CPA)**************************

Comment: It would help to show us your op-amp circuit. Otherwise we're merely speculating. Also, there are more than guys here :)

Comment: 2.5V delta across an LM237 is right on the limit ....

Comment: What does the output of the MAX735 look like?  Does it keep a stiff -5V when the -2.5V rail dips?

Comment: @AdamLawrence LMP7721 is setup as a transimpedence amplifier. I have 3 circuits - all work fine with -2.5V supplied through dual power supply. All respond the same way when plugged into this power circuit. And my mistake :)!

Comment: @Trevor I know right! :S

Comment: @calcium3000 Output of MAX735 dips down to -3.185V when -2.5 rail dips

Comment: YOu may want to switch to a low dropout regulator, something like a LT3091

Comment: whats your load current?

Comment: Why do you have three capacitors in series on the output?

Comment: @Trevor Load current is 10mA- super low

Comment: @sstobbe I did it because it seemed to be more stable than 100uF like the datasheet suggested

Comment: If your load is only 10mA then switch to a low dropout regulator... or a simple emitter follower

Comment: I'd also be using a capacitive inverter like a MAX828

Comment: @Trevor alright I'll check them out. Thanks so much!

Comment: I would not recommend doing that with electrolytics as its hard to manage the polarity of each cap over time, it should run fine with 100uF

Comment: Use one low-ESR electrolytic for the output, not 3 in series. Are you trying to increase capacitance? You connect them in **parallel**, which also reduces the ESR to 1/3. Also make sure the diode is a Schottky type- your symbol shows an ordinary diode. The MAX735 is capable of supplying 275mA typically, which completely outclasses most of the charge pump types, if you have it used correctly.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I modified my board to only have 1 100uF cap now. The diode I'm using is a shottky type diode. After removing 2 of the 100uF caps, the circuit started to short, so I believe you're right- I need to triple check things are setup properly.